# Is it possible to stream in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-vr

I am working in a vr game for Android in unity and it has a quiet large map and many objects to render and my phone doesn't has enough power to run my game so i was thinking that is it possible to stream my game made for desktop pc to my android device inside unity without using any other external software. And also i need to use my phone's gyroscope to control the game.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are talking about is called remote rendering. As you said you don't want to use any other external software you will have to decide and implement everything by yourself. The trickiest part in this will be the streaming of the game view to the phone: there are implementations that send every single frame over a TCP connection. If you want to use something external you could investigate into WebRTC implementations like [this](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/network/webrtc-video-chat-68030).

By the way, what you are trying to achieve is already available as a product, e.g. [here](https://www.trinusvirtualreality.com)

Comment: Yes, it has an SDK you can use in Unity: https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/integration/trinus-pc-vr-for-unity-57952

Comment: Do you still have any doubts? Otherwise could you please mark my answer as solution?